# Watch Vuex state change not working as expected with v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've created a global error state with Vuex, i'ts an array with objects of all current errors.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    errors: []
  },

  getters: {
    getErrors: state => state.errors
  },

  mutations: {
    setError: (state, message) => {
      state.errors.push({ error: true, message });
    },
    removeError: (state, i) => {
      state.errors.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

I have a component that shows all the errors dynamically using Vuex state and what i'm trying to do is removing all the objects that have the error property set to false, the error property state is being handled by the setError mutation and the v-model property inside the component.

I'm trying to do that by watching for changes and removing the desired items from the array, but it is not removing right when the property changes to false, how can i achieve that?

Here is the live demo https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-h5hf7

```
<template>
  <div id="snackbar">
    <v-snackbar
      v-for="(error, index) in getErrors"
      :key="index"
      v-model="error.error"
      color="red"
      :right="true"
      :timeout="2000"
      :top="true"
    >
      {{ error.message }}
      <v-btn dark text @click="removeError(index)">Close</v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "ErrorSnackbar",

  computed: mapGetters(["getErrors"]),

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["removeError"]),
    removeError(i) {
      this.$store.commit("removeError", i);
    }
  },

  watch: {
    getErrors: {
      handler(newErrors) {
        if (newErrors.length > 0) {
          newErrors.forEach((error, i) => {
            if (error.error === false) {
              newErrors.splice(i, 1);
            }
          });
        }
      },
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your watcher will only respond to mutations of the array directly (such as an item being added or removed from it). In order to observe changes to the items within the array too, you need to use a deep watcher.

Also whenever you are looping over an array and removing items from the array at the same time, you should iterate in reverse order otherwise you will miss some elements.

```js
watch: {
  getErrors: {
    deep: true,
    handler(newErrors) {
      for (let i = newErrors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!newErrors[i].error) {
          newErrors.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this may trigger another call to the handler since you're mutating the thing you are observing.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-h5hf7).

The issue has to do with `<v-snackbar>` not updating the model. I'm not completely sure how `<v-snackbar>` is implemented, but it seems that when the component is reused then its timeout gets cancelled and it will not emit an `input` event. Some of the components are getting reused as a result of adding and removing multiple errors at the same time.

What you need to do is to key each `<v-snackbar>` correctly to the same `error` object. Right now you have them keyed by the index in the array, but this will change as elements are removed from the array. So we have to come up with our own unique ID for each error object.

Here's an excerpt of the code changes you need to make:

```
// Define this at file-level
let nextKey = 1

mutations: {
  setError: (state, message) => {
    state.errors.push({
      key: nextKey++,
      error: true,
      message,
    })
  }
}
```

```vue
<v-snackbar
  v-for="error in getErrors"
  :key="error.key"
>
```

Comment: I've tried with deep enabled, but for some reason it messes with the v-model behavior and some errors do not change to false.

Comment: That might be because you aren't looping over the array backwards. See my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately still not work as expected, it can't handle multiple errors in the array for some reason, actually is the same behavior of my loop with deep enabled.

Comment: Then something else must be happening. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thanks for that. It has to do with `<v-snackbar>` and the `v-for`. See my edit.